# How do I get EF6 Migrations working again for .NET 4.6.1 class library?

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I have a .NET Framework 4.6.1 class library project. I (normally) perform code-first migrations on that project using EF6. (The last time was just two months ago.) The model and the migrations are in the library. A couple things have changed since that last time:

1. I installed .NET Core 1.1 on my machine for a totally different project and VS solution.
2. I moved the folder of THIS project off my C drive user folder and onto my D drive.

I can no longer create migrations.

When I attempt to `add-migration` from the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio (`add-migration AddSamples -ConfigurationTypeName Development`), the console responds with:

> Add-Migration: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ConfigurationTypeName'.

If I try it without that parameter, the response is

> Cannot execute this command because Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design is not installed. Install the version of that package that matches the installed version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and try again.

That's a bizarre response (to me), because my package.config file does NOT reference EntityFrameworkCore -- just EntityFramework and EntityFramework6.Npgsql.

If I try to do it from the command line, I use `dnx ef migrations add AddSamples -c "Development"`, and in response, I get:

> Error: Unable to resolve project from D:\Repositories\MySolution\MyClassLibraryProject

I get the same response for ANY `dnx ef` command, even `--help`.

In case it matters, when I run `dnvm list` from that folder, I get

> 1.0.0-beta5 clr
>      1.0.0-beta5 coreclr
>      1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr (default)
>      1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr

And when I run `dnx` by itself, I get

> Microsoft .NET Execution environment Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16231

Is there a way to resolve these error messages and get this working again?

EDIT: here is my packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AWSSDK.Core" version="3.3.7" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="AWSSDK.S3" version="3.3.5.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EntityFramework6.Npgsql" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Npgsql" version="3.1.8" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="4.0.2.206221351" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Comment: just to be clear: You are trying to use code-first migrations for your net46 project? And you are using dnx to compile the project? Is it a classical .csproj with package.config or a .xproj with project.json? Another question? Why are you using dnx? It's been superseeded by the dotnet cli quite a while ago if I'm not completely mistaken. Some more information would be appreciated.

Comment: Your Visual Studio version could help as well. Especially: Have you installed VS 2017? For me installing VS 2017 messed up the dotnet core tooling completely.

Comment: VS 2015. I would gladly use the dotnet cli, but when I run `dotnet ef migrations add AddSamples -c "Development"`, I get "No executable found matching command 'dotnet-ef'" in response, even though I get a proper response from  a simple `dotnet` command and `dotnet --help`, and it's in my Path properly, and works fine on a different project.

Comment: I have not installed VS 2017. This is a classic .csproj with package.config.

Comment: Okay, if it's a classic dotnet .csproj: using `dotnet ef` will not work since you have to install the package as a tool before using it. I'm pretty sure that `dnx ef` is deprecated and won't help you either. So normally `Add-Migration` would be the way to go. Which version of EF are you using/ can you post the EF entries from your packages.config?

Comment: I'm using EF6. I've edited the question to include my packages.config.